# Javascript: I cannot draw image on the canvas

Tags: javascript

I already create my canvas on my page, however when I try to import an image on the canvas, it does not appear, here are the code I used. (the makeGameArea is a method I created to make a canvas on the webpage, the code of this method is not shown because it is so long to put it here)

Here are the following code that should have problem

```
var myGameArea2 = makeGameArea(700, 150, "myArea", "white");
var myContext2 = myGameArea2.getContext("2d");

var myImage = new drawImage(myContext2, "sonic.gif", 91, 97, 0, 0);
myImage.draw();

function drawImage(ctx, src, width, height, x, y){
     this.image = new Image();
     this.image.src = src;
     this.width = width;
     this.height = height;
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
     this.draw = function(){
         this.image.onload = function(){                  
             ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height); 
         }
     }
```

}

Is there anything wrong with my drawImage() method?

Comment: Where is `makeGameArea` defined?

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTMLImage.`onload` will fire only once per `src` setting.

Here you are attaching your handler in the `draw` method, which I guess will be called later on. At this moment, the event will already have fired, and hence will never be called, since it won't fire again <sub>unless you reset its `src`</sub>.

Fixed code block:

```js
function drawImage(ctx, src, width, height, x, y){
     this.image = new Image();
     this.width = width;
     this.height = height;
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
     this.draw = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height));
        };
     // if you want it to draw as soon as possible
     this.image.onload = this.draw.bind(this);
     this.image.src = src;
     }
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I want to happen. Could you please explain to me what does the bind(this) do in the draw method?

Comment: Normally, event handlers are *bound* to the element on which the event fires. This means that in our case, `this` inside the `draw` method, would have represented the `Image` element, not your object. By using `Function.bind`, you can overwrite the default value of `this` in the returned function (`bind()` returns a new function). In ES6, this can be avoided with arrow functions `()=>` where the `this` points to the one of the calling scope (in this case it would  be your object) : `this.draw => ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.x ...; this.image.onload = this.draw`